# Jquery object, how can I access

Tags: jquery, object

Sorry for the beginners question: I get this json return from a php controller regarding form validation:

> {"result":"error","data":{"abbreviation":{"_empty":"This field cannot
>   be left empty"},"description": {"_empty":"This field cannot be left
>   empty"}}}

I already know that I can access each form field in my jquery via:

```
success: function (response, status) {
    if(status === "success") {
        console.log('success post');
        if(response.result === "error") {
            console.log('validation error');
            console.log(response.data.abbreviation);
            console.log(response.data.description);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem now is that "_empty" can have another text as this depends on the validation error type. How can I now access just the validation error message text regardless whats the "key" of this node?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.keys` to get all `keys` in `response.data`

then, you can iterate over those `keys` and read `response.data[key]._empty`

another option is to use `for(var key in response.data)`